# Pass key-value pair array as hidden in html form and access it

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter- HMVC structure. 
I have an array `$listp` in key-value pair format:
Heres what it looks like:

```
    array( 
     [1] => 12, 
     [3] => 33)
```

I need to pass this to a view file and hide it.
Say suppose like the below format:

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'billing/savebill'?>">
    <input type=text name="billarr" id="billarr" value="<?php print_r($listp);?>" />
    </form>
```

And then in Billing controller:i need to retrieve this in the same key-value format

```
 function savebill()
    {
         $data = array();
         $data = $this->input->post('billarr');
    }
```

How do i achieve this?
Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: convert your array to json string. then pass to input and decode in controller.

Comment: If you want to hide this from the end-user entirely, then consider storing in a session variable instead of hidden form fields.

Comment: If you have this array __before__ rendering view, then get this array same way after form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'billing/savebill'?>">
    <input type=text name="billarr" id="billarr" value="<?php json_encode($listp);?>" />
    </form>
```

In save bill

```
function savebill()
    {

         $data = $this->input->post('billarr');
         $data = json_decode($data);
    }
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Hey Bikesh M Annur, i tried it. But when i am printing $data, it saves a null value.

Comment: can you just check with print_r($_REQUEST);